# Help with old iPhoto Library. Can't show package content

Tags: photos.app

I finally managed to decrypt an old backup of an iPhoto Library.
The result was a file without an extension (maybe I removed it back then?) and the following header:
`./._iPhoto Library`

Now I have no idea how to open that library. Photos.app won't open it (start with option + shift, choose library), the iPhoto Library Updater won't either.
It was definitely a library that you could open as folder (right click, show package content), I think from iPhoto 11.
Is there a way to tell macOS that this is a package file? Or even a folder instead of a file?

Comment: Untested - the original name would have been iPhoto Library.photolibrary Adding the .photolibrary extension was what made the OS recognise it as a package. Photos, on the other hand, uses .photoslibrary [extra 's']

Comment: I tried adding the extension. But it didn't work... Maybe it's because the file is on a NAS (ext4) mounted via afp.

Comment: possibly - I've nothing I can test that on